# Hierarchical route parameters in Angular Dart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have this simple test setting: a route `A` with a parameter `parA`, and a subroute `B` with parameter `parB`.

```dart
    'A' : ngRoute 
    (
        path : '/A/:parA',
        enter: (RouteEnterEvent e)
        {
            print ('ENTERED A');
            e.parameters.keys.forEach(print);
        },
        mount: 
        {
            'B' : ngRoute
            (
                path: '/B/:parB',
                enter: (RouteEnterEvent e)
                {
                    print ('ENTERED B');
                    e.parameters.keys.forEach(print);
                }
            )
        }
    )
```

When I go to `/#/A/1234/B/5678` I'd expect to get

```
Entered B 
parA
parB
```

Instead I get

```
Entered A
parA
Entered B
parB
```

Meaning that a component created in `B` whose constructor has a `RouteProvider` can't access the parameter `parA`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be related to this issue https://github.com/angular/route.dart/issues/85.
Maybe the workaround listed there works for you too.

copied from the issue:

> As a current workaround I have a helper method that goes through all
>   parent routes and adds them to the RouteEvent.

```dart
/// Adds the parameters of all parent routes to [e].
RouteEvent _addParentParams(RouteEvent e) {

  // Function to recursively get the parents.
  Function recursiveAddParentParams;
  recursiveAddParentParams = (Route route) {
    // Set the parent parameters to the event.
    e.parameters.addAll(route.parameters);

    if (route.parent != null) {
      recursiveAddParentParams(route.parent);
    }
  };

  recursiveAddParentParams(e.route.parent);

  return e;
}
```